# Algorithm to geo-partition

Tags: algorithm

Problem statement: I have a database of locations and I want to return if a particular location, X is within a specified distance radius. In short, return me all the cities that are within radius of point X in my search.

This solution leads to a brute force search with each point in database. However, in order to optimize the search, if the map is partitioned by certain rings, then that will mean I search within partition 0, the closest partition first and then move out till I am satisfied.

Is there an algorithm that will efficiently partition a map and return location searches based of proximity.

In short:
{A, B, C...} are points in a map. For such points {x} in space, find me all points within distance d of x.

Comment: Easier than partitioning a map into rings, easier than an R-tree: partition the map into squares.  It's simple to figure out which squares lie partly within a circle around your `X`, then compute distances between `X` and any cities in each square.

Comment: If I use this method, that would mean 1. I would have partitioned the map into grids. 2. In my database I have to identity each location with the corresponding grid that location is and store them. 3. Find all the grids where the circle of my test point, p intersects. 4. With those grids find all the locations that are within the range of p.

This seems similar to brute force. How is there an improvement.

Comment: So I have decided to go with Mark's answer to partition the maps into squares. I started with increments of 0.01 on each latitude and longitude. However, the dilemma of this method is that for a country like USA where the ranges of lat and longs are large how do I then efficiently deal with boundary cases.

For example: long range: 60 - 120 that gives a 6000((120-60)) /0.01) boxes and this multiplied by lat: 20-50 which gives 3000 = 18,000,000 boxes => seems like a very huge figure to maintain.

I will have to take a look at the R-tree algotithm to see how I can efficiently use it.

Comment: *18,000,000 boxes => seems like a very huge figure*  It sure does, I'd have thunk that about 1 degree squares would be sufficient.  Your problem statement refers to *cities* not to *hamlets*.  But hey, whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at using either an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) or an [R*-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R*_tree) for this.

I'm not sure what language you are planning on using but [`Boost.geometry`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/rtree_quickstart.html) has a reasonable implementation of these for c++.

For python there is a wrapper for [libspatialindex](https://libspatialindex.github.io/) which does much the same thing in the [Rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/) package.

Comment: Thanks Simon for the suggestion. Was looking at the R-tree. I am wondering how I can use it for my scenario.